# Python plotting realtime data

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly, real-time, bokeh

I am looking for a way to plot realtime data line plot or scatter plots from python.

With the plots I want to monitor long-running loops when experimenting with algorithms with scientific computing. I.e. to help me answer the question: Are my results still improving with each iteration or can I cancel the loop?

I am looking for a quick and dirty method. I saw that with Bokeh and Dash one can program dashboards with realtime updates, but an awful lot of boilerplate code seems to be required just to get an updating plot.

Comment: Try making a notebook and try Voila dashboard, it should be simple to do. You can make the plot in the main thread and update it in separate thread

Comment: @КристиянКацаров Thanks. That makes a dashboard which I really do not need. It does not seem to make a plot that I can update while my algorithm is running. Maybe I did not understand how to use it properly.

Comment: There is an issue, it might help you https://github.com/voila-dashboards/voila/issues/431

Comment: I am also working on such realtime dashboard, if you can share your background update mechanism it would be great!

Comment: The most basic thing you can do would look [like this](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/animation/animation_demo.html). For everything else, the question does not contain enough information to give any useful advise

Comment: Bokeh can certainly do this but as stated, this is not an appropriate question for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thanks, that is just what I was looking for. If you make it an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple "live streaming" example for Bokeh v1.3.0. You can run it with `bokeh serve --show app.py`

app.py:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, curdoc
from datetime import datetime
import random

plot = figure(plot_width = 1200, x_axis_type = 'datetime', tools = 'pan,box_select,crosshair,reset,save,wheel_zoom')
line = plot.line(x = 'time', y = 'value', line_color = 'black', source = dict(time = [datetime.now()], value = [random.randint(5, 10)]))

def update(): 
    line.data_source.stream(dict(time = [datetime.now()], value = [random.randint(5, 10)]))

curdoc().add_root(plot)
curdoc().add_periodic_callback(update, 1000)
```

Comment: Thanks for this self-contained example. For me, the data would be updated from within a loop in an interactive python session. It seems that linking to bokeh would require some inter-process communication, which seems like overkill. Still, have my upvote for providing a complete example.

Comment: If this is in a notebook, there is `push_notebook`, or else you can push data to Standalone Bokeh output with either `AjaxDataSource` or `ServerSentDataSource`

Comment: See also [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55176868/asynchronous-streaming-to-embedded-bokeh-server/55181154#55181154) where another thread is added to take care for the data. And check this Bokeh pages about [Updating From Threads](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html#updating-from-threads)