# How to run and update bokeh server from the tkinter app?

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, bokeh

I want to start bokeh server inside of the tkinter app and update document with plots when button in the app is pressed and data is updated. Server will be run locally on the client computer, no external network capability is needed. I need server to use python callbacks.

I built a simple app that demonstrates this functionality, managed to start bokeh server in separate thread and display initial document. But now I'm stuck with updating document when figures has changed. Here is my code:

```python
import tkinter as tk
from functools import partial
import threading

from bokeh.sampledata.us_marriages_divorces import data as us_marriages_divorces
from bokeh.sampledata.unemployment1948 import data as unemployment1948
from bokeh.plotting import figure, curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import column as column_layout
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Slider
from bokeh.application import Application
from bokeh.application.handlers.function import FunctionHandler
from bokeh.server.server import Server

class PlotBuilder():
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.figures = []
        self.marr = False
        self.data_frame = None
        self.data_source = None

        self.server = None
        self.server_thread = None

    def load_data(self):
        # loading dummy data
        if self.marr:
            print("loading data - unemployment")
            self.data_frame = unemployment1948.copy()
            self.marr = False
        else:
            print("loading data - marriages")
            self.data_frame = us_marriages_divorces.copy()
            self.marr = True

    def build_figures(self):
        # build set of bokeh figures. They end up in self.figures list to be 
        # added  to document via column_layout(self.figures)
        if self.data_frame is None:
            self.load_data()
        print("creating figures")
        self.data_source = ColumnDataSource(self.data_frame)
        x_col = 'Year'
        self.figures = []
        for y_col in self.data_source.column_names:
            if y_col == x_col or y_col == 'index':
                continue
            plot = figure(x_axis_label=x_col, y_axis_label=y_col, 
                          title=y_col, width=800, height=400)
            plot.line(source=self.data_source, x=x_col, y=y_col, 
                      line_width=2, color="red")
            plot.diamond(source=self.data_source, x=x_col, y=y_col, 
                         size=5, color="blue")
            # TODO: add slider and other widgets to each figure later

            self.figures.append(plot)

    def build_document(self, doc):
        # server callback
        #documentation suggests that I need to run curdoc() to make doc 
        # thread-safe, but wherre to run it? I don't have access to doc 
        # anywhere exept here, and here it is passed from 
        # Server() callback

        #doc = curdoc()

        print("Building document...")
        self.build_figures()
        layout = column_layout(self.figures)
        doc.add_root(layout)
        self.figures = []

        # here I'm trying to update document if new figures are 
        # generated. 
        # The function is being run, but won't update. Because of 
        # separate thread?
        def update(doc):
            print("run update()")
            if len(self.figures) > 0:
                print("New figures found, building plot...")
                layout = column_layout(self.figures)
                doc.add_root(layout)
                self.figures = []
        # invoke update periodically
        doc.add_periodic_callback(partial(update, doc=doc), 1000)


    def start_server(self):
        # code to start server, it will be running in separate thread.
        self.server = Server({'/': Application(
            FunctionHandler(self.build_document))}, num_procs=1)
        self.server.start()
        self.server.io_loop.add_callback(self.server.show, '/')
        self.server.io_loop.start()


    def show(self):
        # actual server start in separate thread
        if self.server_thread is None:
            # first run - creating server
            print("Starting server thread...")
            self.server_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.start_server, 
                                                  daemon=True)
            self.server_thread.start()
            print("server thread", self.server_thread)
        else:
            # updating figures  - self.update() doesn't work here, pretty much 
            # expected. Should I communicate with self.thread and run it there?
            #self.update()
            pass


    def update(self, doc):
        # update figures - this method currently isn't used. Documentation suggests 
        # I need to run doc.add_next_tick_callback to update data, 
        # but where to invoke it? Also, it seems not relevant as I need 
        # to replace the whole doc (or layout inside the doc)
        self.build_figures()
        doc.add_next_tick_callback(partial(self.build_document, doc=doc))



# Simple tkinter app. Everything works as expected here.
class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, screenName: str | None = None, baseName: str | None = None, 
                 className: str = "Tk", useTk: bool = True, sync: bool = False, 
                 use: str | None = None) -> None:
        super().__init__(screenName, baseName, className, useTk, sync, use)
        self.plot_builder = PlotBuilder()

        self.title("Bokeh server test app")
        self.geometry("400x300+200+200")

        btn = tk.Button(self, text="Reveal Plot", command=self.reveal_plot)
        btn.grid(column=1, row=0)

        btn2 = tk.Button(self, text="Update Data", command=self.update_data)
        btn2.grid(column=2, row=0)


    def reveal_plot(self):
        # building figures and showing
        self.plot_builder.build_figures()
        self.plot_builder.show()

    def update_data(self):
        # reloading data and building figures
        self.plot_builder.load_data()
        self.plot_builder.build_figures()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

Some comments: `PlotBuilder` is responsible for gathering data and building plots. Also, it manages bokeh server - the part where I stuck.
I can't just update the data source as plots count and type may change between runs in the real app.
init, load_data and build_figures are completely dummy and work as expected.

`App` is a simple demo tkinter app with two buttons. First should display plot, second - update data for plotting. This part works as expected as well.

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55176868/asynchronous-streaming-to-embedded-bokeh-server) and read though relevant bokeh [documentation](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server/app.html#updating-from-threads), but can't adapt it to what I need. I also tried (still trying) to understand how bokeh `serve` subcommand works, with no luck yet.

Any advice is appreciated.